# Assign `delegate` function before the object that owns the function is instantiated

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic, delegates

I'm working on a system where a `Watcher` can be set up to be interested in an `Event` and invoke an `Action` if an `Event` of the correct type is passed in.

Now the `Action` requires information about the `Event` when invoked.

In the below code I use delegates as `Action` properties (not a property in a .NET fashion, just a field/member/whatever...) to which I pass the Event functions when setting up the `Watcher`.

The Problem of course with the code is that at *//Step3*, when I do that, the field `TheEvent` is null. And it will only be known once the `Watcher` is passed the `Event`.

How can I tell the `Watcher` to make it's `Action` get the required properties from the `Event` before the `Event` is assigned?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
using System;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Step1: choose the IEvent: NumericEvent
        //Step2: create Watcher<NumbericEvent>
        Watcher<NumericEvent> aWatcher = new Watcher<NumericEvent>();

        //Step3: Choose and add an action
        aWatcher.TheAction = new AlphaAction();

        //Step3 bind the ActionProperties
        aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = aWatcher.TheEvent.GetProperty1;
        aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyB = aWatcher.TheEvent.GetProperty2;


        //Step4 Bind the event
        NumericEvent anEvent = new NumericEvent();
        aWatcher.Call(anEvent);


    }
}

internal class AlphaAction
{
    internal delegate string ActionPropertyA();
    internal delegate int ActionPropertyB();

    internal ActionPropertyA AnActionPropertyA;
    internal ActionPropertyB AnActionPropertyB;
    internal string ActionPropertyC;

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.Write(AnActionPropertyA.Invoke());
        Console.Write(AnActionPropertyB.Invoke());
    }
}


internal interface IEvent
{
}

internal class NumericEvent:IEvent
{
    internal string EventProperty1 = "Property1";
    internal int EventProperty2 = 2;

    internal string GetProperty1()
    {
        return EventProperty1;
    }
    internal int GetProperty2()
    {
        return EventProperty2;
    }

}

internal class Watcher<T> where T:IEvent
{
    internal NumericEvent TheEvent;
    internal AlphaAction TheAction;

    internal void Call(IEvent anEvent)
    {
        TheEvent = (NumericEvent)anEvent;
        TheAction.Run();
    }
}
}
```

Maybe a completely different approach needs to be taken but I hope this gets the problem and the desired outcome across.

---

**UPDATE**

I've made some progerss with using Delegate.CreateDelegate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3860fy3.aspx) but it's still not quite right as it's treating it as static if null when assigned:

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Step1: choose the IEvent: NumericEvent
        //Step2: create Watcher<NumbericEvent>
        Watcher<NumericEvent> aWatcher = new Watcher<NumericEvent>();

        //Step3: Choose and add an action
        aWatcher.TheAction = new AlphaAction();

        //Step3 bind the ActionProperties

        MethodInfo method1 = typeof(NumericEvent).GetMethod("GetProperty1");
        aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = (AlphaAction.ActionPropertyA)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(AlphaAction.ActionPropertyA), aWatcher.TheEvent, method1);

        MethodInfo method2 = typeof(NumericEvent).GetMethod("GetProperty2");
        aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyB = (AlphaAction.ActionPropertyB)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(AlphaAction.ActionPropertyB), aWatcher.TheEvent, method2);

        //Step4 an event is created and passed to the Watcher
        NumericEvent anEvent = new NumericEvent("bla",3);
        if (aWatcher.GType() == anEvent.GetType())
            aWatcher.Call(anEvent);

    }
}

internal abstract class BaseAction
{
    public abstract void Run();
}

internal class AlphaAction: BaseAction
{
    internal delegate string ActionPropertyA();
    internal delegate int ActionPropertyB();

    internal ActionPropertyA AnActionPropertyA;
    internal ActionPropertyB AnActionPropertyB;
    internal string ActionPropertyC;

    public override void Run()
    {
        Console.Write(AnActionPropertyA.Invoke());
        Console.Write(AnActionPropertyB.Invoke());
    }
}


internal interface IEvent
{
}

internal class NumericEvent : IEvent
{
    private readonly string _eventProperty1;
    private readonly int _eventProperty2;

    public NumericEvent(string p1, int p2)
    {
        _eventProperty1 = p1;
        _eventProperty2 = p2;
    }

    public string GetProperty1()
    {
        return _eventProperty1;
    }
    public int GetProperty2()
    {
        return _eventProperty2;
    }

}

internal class Watcher<T> where T:IEvent
{
    internal T TheEvent;
    internal AlphaAction TheAction;

    internal Type GType()
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }

    internal void Call(IEvent anEvent)
    {
        TheEvent = (T)anEvent;
        TheAction.Run();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My main point is to not have the Action dependent on the Event but have the watcher wire the right Event properties to the Action. There can be multiple Actions (with different subclass implementations for Actions) for a Watcher (and therefore the same event) and the same Action may be used by different Watchers, ie may be invoked with different Events. So the Action should be separated from the Event entirely. The Action just needs to know how to get it's values

Comment: I'm getting closer to a solution using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` but it's not quite right yet.... `MethodInfo method1 = typeof(NumericEvent).GetMethod("GetProperty1");
   aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = (AlphaAction.ActionPropertyA)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(AlphaAction.ActionPropertyA), aWatcher.TheEvent, method1);`

Comment: So `aWatcher.TheEvent` is null at the time when `createDelegate` is called but not when the delegate `AnActionPropertyA` is invoked. --> Is there a way to make it use the then assigned `aWatcher.TheEvent`?

Comment: It sounds a little like domain events. I have an implementation [here](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/01/event-bus-implementation.html). (There are lots of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `aWatcher.TheEvent` in the `aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = aWatcher.TheEvent.GetProperty1;` line (and in the updated code `aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = (AlphaAction.ActionPropertyA)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(AlphaAction.ActionPropertyA), aWatcher.TheEvent, method1);`).

Because `aWatcher.TheEvent` is `null` at the time the delegate is created the delegate **always** uses `null`. It doesn't care that you later assign the event in the line `TheEvent = (NumericEvent)anEvent;`.

To get this to work you need to let the delegate know that there is a class coming in the future. Here's how I would do it, but I suspect this will break something in your logic of how you want it to work.

```
void Main()
{
    Watcher<NumericEvent> aWatcher = new Watcher<NumericEvent>();
    aWatcher.TheAction = new AlphaAction<NumericEvent>();
    aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = ne => ne.GetProperty1();
    aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyB = ne => ne.GetProperty2();
    NumericEvent anEvent = new NumericEvent("bla", 3);
    if (aWatcher.GType() == anEvent.GetType())
        aWatcher.Call(anEvent);
}

internal abstract class BaseAction<T> where T : IEvent
{
    public abstract void Run(T theEvent);
}

internal class AlphaAction<T> : BaseAction<T> where T : IEvent
{
    internal delegate string ActionPropertyA(T theEvent);
    internal delegate int ActionPropertyB(T theEvent);

    internal ActionPropertyA AnActionPropertyA;
    internal ActionPropertyB AnActionPropertyB;

    public override void Run(T theEvent)
    {
        Console.Write(AnActionPropertyA(theEvent));
        Console.Write(AnActionPropertyB(theEvent));
    }
}

internal interface IEvent
{
}

internal class NumericEvent : IEvent
{
    private readonly string _eventProperty1;
    private readonly int _eventProperty2;

    public NumericEvent(string p1, int p2)
    {
        _eventProperty1 = p1;
        _eventProperty2 = p2;
    }

    public string GetProperty1()
    {
        return _eventProperty1;
    }
    public int GetProperty2()
    {
        return _eventProperty2;
    }
}

internal class Watcher<T> where T : IEvent
{
    internal AlphaAction<T> TheAction;

    internal Type GType()
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }

    internal void Call(T theEvent)
    {
        TheAction.Run(theEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the problem. Much more to the point than what I wrote in 1000 lines :). I think I can get away with making the Action generic, so your answer might just work. Thanks.

Comment: This worked well @Enigmativity but I'm facing another issue now. `aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = ne => ne.GetProperty1();` can't be set at a time when the `Action` is already instantiated. Instead I'm converting the string representation of `AlphaAction<NumericEvent>` into an actual instance of an `Action` like this `dynamic actionInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(ActionType);` (it may be a different `XyAction<123Event>`) so I cannot do `aWatcher.TheAction.AnActionPropertyA = ne => ne.GetProperty1();` because the type of ne is unknown and so `GetProperty1()` is not available! Ideas?

Comment: @EasierSaidThanDone - What is it that you're trying to do with this code? One level of abstraction up?

Comment: Pretty much. I want to allow any kind of `Event` passed to any kind of `Action`. When a managing class instantiates the `Action<Event>`, it can specify the `Event` type and can also specify for each of the `Action`'s properties which `Event` property maps to it. So at the time of specifying, the instance of an `Action` exists, the instance of the `Event` however doesn't. At some stage, an `Event` instance of the correct Type is passed to the `Action<Event>` and the `Action` can then invoke the `Event`s properties that are mapped to it's own ones. Hope that brings the idea across well.

Comment: @EasierSaidThanDone - No, I meant one level of abstraction higher. What are you trying to do this for?

Comment: OK, got you, @Enigmativity. It's a system where certain activities a user does can trigger an event. For example a user signing up creates a userSignsUpEvent with parameters specific to that event, e.g email and date. Then there is an agent that the receives the events.

Comment: Actions may be registered with that agent and get executed. These actions need the event's parameters. E.g. a SendWelcomeEmailAction needs the email address to send a welcome email. Now there are going to be a large number of different events and actions and they can be combined by a system admin at will. There could be another action registered for the event above, using the same event parameters in a different way

Comment: @EasierSaidThanDone - It sounds like you need an event bus. There are many of those around so you really shouldn't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your need well then you can make use of [Galasoft's MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/nuget/).

The point is the following:

- Define a message type, e.g. `SomeMessage`
- Register for this type of message where you want to be notified.
- An "event" can be raised by sending an instance of `SomeMessage`.
- All the action will be executed that are registered for this message.

Let's take an example:

```
// First you create the message with the needed properties.
public SomeMessage
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

// Then at some places you register for listening to this type of message
Messenger.Default.Register<SomeMessage>(
    this,
    message => YourMethodThatProcessesTheMessage(message)
);

// Your method knows the exact type of the message
// So you can access all the properties of the message
private void YourMethodThatProcessesTheMessage(SomeMessage message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message.Content);
}

// At another place you can simply send a message to all the listeners
var message = new SomeMessage() { Content = "something" };
Messenger.Default.Send<SomeMessage>(message);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I get your point right, there would be a dependency between Action and Even which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I would say that `SomeMessage` is only a kind of `EventArgs` not the `event` itself. You can register for this message in multiple places and define different actions there. Of course `SomeMessage` can have `Action<T>` delegate properties and you can set the delegate when you instantiate the `SomeMessage`, e.g. `var message = new SomeMessage() { ActionA = YourMethod, ActionB = YourOtherMethod };` and the receiver will just execute them, e.g. `message.ActionA();`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to do the following: Have a `Watcher` class which looks for a specific event and when it gets passed to the class an action should be fired and the event should be passed in as argument.

I do not fully understand why you need the hole thing and why you set up the things the way you did but here is a simple implementation that might help:

```
internal interface IEvent { }

internal class Watcher<T> where T : IEvent
{
    internal Action<T> Action;

    public void On(IEvent evnt)
    {
        if (evnt is T) Action?.Invoke((T) evnt);
    }
}
```

You can create new events by implementing `IEvent` and you can register actions which should be fired when an action by the specified type is registered by the watcher by setting the `Action` field. e.g.

```
var watcher = new Watcher<NumberEvent>();
watcher.Action += e => Console.WriteLine($"Got a number: {e.Number}");

watcher.On(new StringEvent { Text = "hello"});
watcher.On(new NumberEvent { Number = 1337});
```

when these are defined

```
internal class NumberEvent : IEvent
{
    internal int Number;
}

internal class StringEvent : IEvent
{
    internal string Text;
}
```

If I did not understand your problem correctly (and there is a great chance I did not) please explain what your program is supposed to do.

Here are some thoughts/questions on your implementation:

- You are creating a generic watcher class (`Watcher<T>`) but `T` is not used inside of the watcher. You might want to replace `NumericEvent` by `T` and do some checking if the specified `IEvent` is of the type `T` (or in your case `NumericEvent`). Your coding makes `IEvent` pretty much obsolete.
- C# has properties `string EventProperty { get; }`. You do not have to make a `GetProperty1()` method (also your field is internal so why use the method?)
- Just supply the event to the action and do not try to hotwire the event to the action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main point is to not have the Action dependent on the Event but have the watcher wire the right Event properties to the Action. There can be multiple Actions (with different subclass implementations for Actions) for a Watcher (and therefore the same event) and the same Action may be used by different Watchers, ie may be invoked with different Events. So the Action should be separated from the Event entirely. The Action just needs to know how to get it's values. Re your final points: In production code you'd certainly do it like that, this is just an example :)